# find_or_initialize_by_title uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I've got a text_field for tags in a nested form(It's being associated with Trips) that is being split on a comma on save and saving the words in the string seperated by the comma. I've jumped through some hoops to make it happen, and it's happening as I want by now. The only downside is that it seems that it doesn't make the current tag a unique tag(If it exists associate the existing one with the new Trip instead of making a new tag)

Here's the code splitting and saving the tag seperately:

```
if params[:trip][:tags_attributes].present?
  params[:trip][:tags_attributes].each do |tag| 
   @a = tag[1]['title']
   @a.split(',').each do |single|
      @trip.tags.find_or_initialize_by_title(single)  
   end
  end
end
```

And just in case my Trip.rb:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :user_id, 
  :triplocations_attributes, :photo, :category_ids, 
  :start_city, :tripphotos_attributes, :img_url, :thumb_url, :images,
  :tags_attributes, :province

  # validates :title, :length => {:minimum => 3}
  # validates :description, :presence => true
  # validates_associated :tags


  has_many :triplocations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tripphotos, :dependent => :destroy

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :triplocations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tripphotos, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use Tags.find_or_initialize_by_title(single) and then assign to the relation.

Comment: SOrry for my late response, had other issues to address. Thanks for your comment but could you help me out with a little code. I'm kinda noobish :-p